# Admob displaying in xml preview but not when run in mobile device

Tags: android, adview, adbannerview, admob

I have a problem with admob where I am able to see the preview of white banner in xml layout whereas when I run it I am unable to see the banner in mobile screen.

I have done all necessary work in order to integrate admob with credentials.

Here is my activity file

```
AdView mAdView;
AdRequest adRequest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ads_layout);

    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

}
```

Here is my xml layout with relative layout wrapped as parent

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
  </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Here below is my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name=".CompassNavApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/qiblacompass"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.Main2Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

1-Check if there is anny other view comming in front of the adview (Try to remove all other view and test)

2-if you are using your ad unit not the dummy wich is `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111`,Check you connection because if there was a probleme in the connection the ad will not show, and you wont even know about it !!

-I recommend you to use the dummy id and check-

Comment: I am not even able to display blank banner that is the problem..i have removed all other views .. you can just check my xml displayed above